# how to Replace each character with other character in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, replace

I'm trying to make a textarea input field which automatically replaces specific characters to different characters; example: when a user types "a" character it should be automatically replaced with "o" character. I'm new to jquery so can you please tell what's wrong with the following code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#myTextBox').keyup(function() {
        $("a").replaceWith( "o" );
        $("z").replaceWith( "N" );
        $("y").replaceWith( "M" );
        $("p").replaceWith( "f" );
        $("v").replaceWith( "K" );
        $("b").replaceWith( "P" );
    });
});
```

I appreciate your help, thank you

**edit:**

thank you all, the following worked as expected:

```
$(function() {
    $('#myTextBox').keyup(function() {

        $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/a/g, "o"));

    });
});
```

Comment: The jquery selector is meant for selecting dom elements. Not to select value from  a text box. you should be using the `val()` function to get the values

Comment: RE: "is that correct?"  Well, have you tried it in your application?

Comment: I changed the code an used val() function, but not sure if that's correct..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all `$("a")` actually targets all anchor elements on the page, so I'm guessing that's not what you want (and others don't even exist, except p, so your selector will return nothing).  Secondly, you can use [regular expressions to do your replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) without any special jQuery code.

Instead of:

```
$("a").replaceWith( "o" );
```

Try:

```
$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/a/g, "o"));
```

To break that down:

```
var oldValue = $(this).val();
var newValue = oldValue.replace(/a/g, "o");

// Set to new value
$(this).val(newValue);
```

Comment: This is okay for the given example, but it won't work for a solution with transitive replacements without being done carefully (and it won't work at all if it's cyclic in the end). Imagine what happens if you also have a rule replacement for "o" but you do the `a->o` replacement first and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @Platinum, good point.  Works in this case, but great comment.

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/2fYdT/69/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".normal").each(function() {
        var text = $(this).html();
        text = text.replace(/"/g, '');
        $(this).html(text);
    });
});
```

for something like this:

```
<div class="normal">Lorem "ipsum "dolor"</div>
```

Result:

```
<div class="normal">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
```